# Downloading large data in small chunk and simultaneously display in UI

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a web API (SOAP based) which return data in JSON format.

The input parameter for this web API is time duration which user gives.

I am calling this web API using async-task in my android app to display these data in UI.
Its working perfectly fine till I give small duration i.e. 1 hr, 2 hrs or 3 hrs.
but I try to get data for full day I get OOM error or some time I dont get error it take lot of time to parse and display that data in UI.

When I give one day as input, its return huge data as we cant have unlimited memory we need use some different mechanism.

I hope this is common problem you must have faced.
How I could solve this problem?

Do we have in sample code where I get data in small chunk (lets say 2 hrs) in loop and once I get first data I start display this at UI and simultaneously I download the next 2 hrs data?

or please suggest some other solution?

Comment: Only download as much data as you are displaying? Or if you want to download large data use an intent service?

Comment: The answer depends on the structure of data received. Can you post an example structure of response from web service ?

Comment: @skynet  Sorry if I am not clear in my original question. Structure are very simple it has lot of LatLog pair, I need to draw in map and connect them with polyline. What I am looking for is to use concurrent way to get the data from server through web API as well as start drawing the data at UI so any good way to download one buffer and draw the other buffer at UI.

Answer (score 0):

you can divide the input time duration in to hours and make a call to async task for each hour then parse it and update the UI, in this way you minimizing the load.

And for the problem parsing large json. you can use Gson streaming from Gson Library [Gson Streaming to read and write JSON](http://www.mkyong.com/java/gson-streaming-to-read-and-write-json/)

or you can use JsonReader. [JsonReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html)

hope it gives you some information on solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If large no. of data coming,you need to check if you returning an image for every record? If that the case you need to check image size because large size of images causes of OOM (Out of Memory) exception.You can use Universal image loader or Picasso image loading libraries to resize the image.

If you are using listview or gridview ,it is recommended to use ViewHolder pattern.This will not create a new cell every time you scroll but create a new cell for the first time only.

If large no. of data coming ,you need to design your query that provide records in batching. You need to pass start limit and number of record you want to return.And in android,you can use load more listview or recycleview.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

https://codentrick.com/load-more-recyclerview-bottom-progressbar/

> it take lot of time to parse and display that data in UI.

by implementing above mechanism like pagination or batching using load more lisview you can defiantly reduce parse time of your response and OOM error.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for updating late. I able to solve it using pagination.